# How to filter minute data using day and symbol?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

Assuming I have a dataframe of minute OHLC:

```
                       timestamp    open    high     low  ...      vwap  symbol  volume_10_day        date
0      2022-09-22 08:00:00+00:00  3.8400  3.9700  3.8400  ...  3.898279     APE           None  2022-12-22
1      2022-09-22 08:05:00+00:00  3.9100  3.9600  3.9000  ...  3.913727     APE           None  2022-12-22
2      2022-09-22 08:10:00+00:00  3.9300  3.9500  3.9000  ...  3.927569     APE           None  2022-12-22
3      2022-09-22 08:15:00+00:00  3.9300  3.9500  3.9200  ...  3.922965     APE           None  2022-12-22
4      2022-09-22 08:20:00+00:00  3.9500  3.9800  3.9500  ...  3.965291     APE           None  2022-12-22
...                          ...     ...     ...     ...  ...       ...     ...            ...         ...
21288  2022-12-24 00:35:00+00:00  2.2400  2.2400  2.2200  ...  2.227360    XPON           None  2022-12-23
21289  2022-12-24 00:40:00+00:00  2.2488  2.2488  2.2488  ...  2.248800    XPON           None  2022-12-23
21290  2022-12-24 00:45:00+00:00  2.2500  2.2500  2.2200  ...  2.227422    XPON           None  2022-12-23
21291  2022-12-24 00:50:00+00:00  2.2500  2.2500  2.2200  ...  2.229057    XPON           None  2022-12-23
21292  2022-12-24 00:55:00+00:00  2.2395  2.2395  2.1700  ...  2.202498    XPON           None  2022-12-23

[21293 rows x 11 columns]
```

And a DF of daily data:

```
   level_0  index        date symbol  ...  change_1_day  change_10_day  volume_10_day  volume_1_day
0    22177  22177  2022-12-20   ICCM  ...    177.599829           None           None       30005.0
1    30404  30404  2022-12-22    APE  ...     75.182482           None           None        2224.0
2    46210  46210  2022-12-21   SINT  ...     57.161981           None           None      857345.0
3    47737  47737  2022-12-23   XPON  ...    139.185751           None           None         284.0
```

How can I use the second dataframe to filter the first, so that I only get back a DF of minute data which contain the symbol and days of the second DF?

I have tried the answer suggested by inquirer:

```
dfm = pd.read_sql_query("SELECT * from ohlc_minutes", conn)
dfd = pd.read_sql_query("SELECT * from filtered_ohlc_init", conn)

df = pd.DataFrame()

def my_func(x):
    global df
    ind = x.index[0]
    aaa = dfd[(dfd['date'] == x['date'][ind]) & (dfd['symbol'] == x['symbol'][ind])]
    if len(aaa) > 0:#match found add these rows
        df = pd.concat([df, x])

dfm.groupby('date').apply(my_func)
```

But for some reason it returns an even bigger dataframe than the original:

```
                       timestamp    open    high     low  ...      vwap  symbol  volume_10_day        date
11264  2022-09-20 08:10:00+00:00  1.5100  1.5100  1.5100  ...  1.513548    ICCM           None  2022-12-20
11265  2022-09-20 11:40:00+00:00  1.5300  1.5300  1.5300  ...  1.530000    ICCM           None  2022-12-20
11266  2022-09-20 12:05:00+00:00  1.5100  1.5200  1.5100  ...  1.518532    ICCM           None  2022-12-20
11267  2022-09-20 12:20:00+00:00  1.5200  1.5200  1.5200  ...  1.520000    ICCM           None  2022-12-20
11268  2022-09-20 12:55:00+00:00  1.4800  1.4800  1.4800  ...  1.480000    ICCM           None  2022-12-20
...                          ...     ...     ...     ...  ...       ...     ...            ...         ...
21288  2022-12-24 00:35:00+00:00  2.2400  2.2400  2.2200  ...  2.227360    XPON           None  2022-12-23
21289  2022-12-24 00:40:00+00:00  2.2488  2.2488  2.2488  ...  2.248800    XPON           None  2022-12-23
21290  2022-12-24 00:45:00+00:00  2.2500  2.2500  2.2200  ...  2.227422    XPON           None  2022-12-23
21291  2022-12-24 00:50:00+00:00  2.2500  2.2500  2.2200  ...  2.229057    XPON           None  2022-12-23
21292  2022-12-24 00:55:00+00:00  2.2395  2.2395  2.1700  ...  2.202498    XPON           None  2022-12-23

[21293 rows x 11 columns]
```

**UPDATE**

The solution by inquirer does seem to work. It manages to filter out the minutes for two of the symbols (APE and XPON) but for the other two (ICCM and SINT) they do not appear in the final dataframe.

When I run:

```
print(df.groupby('symbol').symbol.nunique())
```

It returns only:

```
symbol
APE     1
XPON    1
```

Comment: Please post a reproducible example to get a better answer:
merge both df (how="left") and then drop_na. You get the date with df["timestamp"].dt.date

Comment: Hi I am not sure what you mean, could you show an example please?

Answer (score 1):

As an option, you can create columns with dates in each dataframe.

```
dfd['day'] = dfd['timestamp'].dt.date
dfm['day'] = dfm['timestamp'].dt.date
```

Make grouping in the minute chart by the 'day' column. Create an empty dataframe and fill in where there are dates and symbol matches.

```
import pandas as pd

dfd['timestamp'] =  pd.to_datetime(dfd['timestamp'], errors='raise')#day
dfm['timestamp'] =  pd.to_datetime(dfm['timestamp'], errors='raise')#minute
dfd['day'] = dfd['timestamp'].dt.date
dfm['day'] = dfm['timestamp'].dt.date


df = pd.DataFrame()

def my_func(x):
    global df
    ind = x.index[0]
    aaa = dfd[(dfd['day'] == x['day'][ind]) & (dfd['symbol'] == x['symbol'][ind])]
    if len(aaa) > 0:#match found add these rows
        df = pd.concat([df, x])

dfm.groupby('day').apply(my_func)

print(df)
```

Output

```
                  timestamp     open     high       vwap symbol         day
0 2020-11-05 09:00:00+00:00  11.2000  11.2000  11.199735    AAL  2020-11-05
1 2020-11-05 09:03:00+00:00  11.0900  11.0900  11.090000    AAL  2020-11-05
2 2020-11-05 09:07:00+00:00  11.1600  11.1800  11.167725    AAL  2020-11-05
3 2020-11-05 09:08:00+00:00  11.1800  11.1800  11.180000    AAL  2020-11-05
4 2020-11-05 09:09:00+00:00  11.1800  11.1800  11.180000    AAL  2020-11-05
5 2022-10-24 20:33:00+00:00  94.6000  94.6000  94.601900   SPOT  2022-10-24
6 2022-10-24 20:41:00+00:00  94.6600  94.6600  94.648500   SPOT  2022-10-24
7 2022-10-24 20:49:00+00:00  94.0000  94.0000  93.959055   SPOT  2022-10-24
8 2022-10-24 22:45:00+00:00  94.5000  94.5000  94.500000   SPOT  2022-10-24
9 2022-10-24 23:59:00+00:00  94.3999  94.3999  94.399162   SPOT  2022-10-24
```

Comment: Hey mate, thanks for this. I have tried your suggestion but for me, it returns an even bigger dataframe than the one it's meant to be filtering. I'm not sure why

Comment: in the date column of the minute timeframe, the dates differ from the timestamp column. I creating columns: dfm['day'] = dfm['timestamp'].dt.date and
dfd['day'] = dfd['date'].dt.date using my code. The result is an empty dataframe, as it should be.

Comment: Thanks mate - that was it! I was setting the wrong date on some of the minute data. Now it's the correct one, your solution works. LEGEND! Thank you!

Comment: Hey mate, not sure why but your solution only returned 2/4 symbols. But I managed to solve it by doing `df = dfm.merge(dfd[['symbol','date']], on=['symbol','date'], how='inner')`. Thanks again for your time and help! Ultimately your idea of adding a date column got me there